# Prove that a binary tree with n leaves has a height of at least log n

Tags: binary-tree, proof

I know that the number of leaves in a binary tree of height `h` can be at most `2^h`, and I also know how to prove this using induction. Where do I go from here?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817413/proof-that-a-binary-tree-with-n-leaves-has-a-height-of-at-least-log-n) previously answered question, but this doesn't make any sense to me because I don't understand what the proof by contradiction in the theorem section has anything to do with a binary tree's height being at least `log(n)`. I was expecting him to talk about how `log(n)` relates to the number of leaves and height, but instead he goes on to talk about how to do a proof by contradiction using `n = 2^a + b`.

Can anyone help me understand how we can prove that the height of a BT with n leaves will be at least log n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a binary tree, and let `h` be its height and `n` be the number of its leaves.

By your first sentence, `n <= 2^h`. Taking a log base 2 on both sides (which preserves the inequality because log is monotonic), we have `log(n) <= h`. That immediately gives you what you wanted: the height is at least `log(n)`, where `n` is the number of leaves.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. In the previously answered question (linked in my original post), what is the purpose of the theorem? According to that same post, establishing that n <= 2^h is just a lemma, which I'm assuming means that it doesn't prove the original statement by itself. Would it not be enough to prove n <= 2^h and then take a log of both sides to show its relationship to the tree's height?

Comment: @user928112 Not sure. I think my proof is just as valid as your linked proof but much more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

So you know that your binary tree has the following properties:

n <= 2^h

Now you can use a log on both sides because both are positive and that's it from a math point of view.

In order to understand it better you can do the following:
If you have a tree which is not full you traded 2 possible leaves for one actual leaf (because there could be 2 children). So the maximum number of leaves for any given height is a full tree which has 2^h leaves or log (n) height.